# What connector is this? I haven't a clue, looks standard though

Tags: pcb, connector, identification, instrumentation-amplifier

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQDg.jpg

I need to get an adapter to connect the plug from the green board, to the plug on the brown board. However, I have no idea what the green board's connector is called, so I can't find the appropriate adapter. Can you lend a hand?

The green board contains tone generators for an electric piano, the signal is then passed though this connector to the brown board, which is the amp. Pins are spaced 2 mm apart

[image: connector part 1]
[image: connector part 2]

Comment: Give us more photos/angles of the connector on the green board. I can't tell what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its PH series JST Connector 5 pin[image]